# Using orchard how to display content itmes & send email to user

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard 1.6 i've setup 3 content parts, each viewable from 3 separate forms, which will automatically navigate from 1,2,3 as the user fills them out (by selecting the booking option on the main menu):

```
1) Records Name & phone number as input fields
2) Records equipment user has selected to rent (from drop down and input fields)
3) Confirmation which should display what the user has entered on the first 2
```

So far im on part (3) so I want to display what the user has chosen for the first 2 forms (I know they are stored as content items) but how can i get both of them to display on the confirmation page.

Also when the 'Submit' button is clicked on the confirmation page i would like to send an email to the owner. How can I do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use the rules module (workflow in 1.7+) to send an email when the content item is created.

To display the data you could create a simple little module that displays the latest two items created by the current user. Or something. I've never really used Orchard Forms so I'm not sure if it has better ways of accessing content you have created with it.

Comment: well they store as a content item...is it possible to create a form that allows you to display multiple content items?